# Path-finding algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

Ok so I have a board and I need to find all possible solutions of it. It **starts at the top left corner** of the board and by only going **horizontally or vertically**, it has to visit each element of the board. In order to successfully move to another element the **first letter or the second letter must match** with the previous. It can only **visit each element once and only once** but it can jump over it. So if I have a board like this:

XY YX XX

XX YY XY

YX XY XX

A sample solution path would be: XY->XX->YX->XX->XY->YY->YX->XX->XY

I was thinking of using BFS but I haven't learned about queues yet so am I able to use it without them? This is in C btw, the reason is that the programming course I'm taking is only covering C.

Comment: Easy: teach yourself about queues :)

Comment: lol the thing is we didn't learn queues and the prof. doesn't expect us to know about them for some reason so I don't want to use it :p

Answer (score 3):

You could try backtracking and pruning. It uses recursion instead of queues.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: Will that return multiple solutions?

Comment: @JoelCornett yes it should return all possible solutions

Comment: you can always break out once you find the first solution

Answer (score 3):

Note that even finding one solution, and not all of them is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem, because of the `visit each element once and only once` constraint. Your problem is actually a variation of the [Hamiltonian-Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) on a grid.

Thus, **there is no known polynomial solution do decide if such a path even exist**, let alone find all of them.

@Doct0rz suggestion to use **backtracking** is probably your best shot to solve this problem. specifically, I'd go for some variation of [**DFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) that maintains `visited` set only for the relevant branch.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
specialDFS(v,visited):
  if (visited.size == |V|):
      print this path by following the "father" field up to the root.
  for each edge (v,u):
     if (u is in visited): //do not check vertices that are already on the path
          continue
     visited.add(u)
     u.father <- v
     specialDFS(u,visited) //recursive call
     visited.remove(u) //clean the work environment, we maintain visited set only for the same path
```

invoke with:

```
visited <- {source} //add the single source here
source.father <- null //source is the root of all paths
specialDFS(source,visited)
```

Note: This is high-level OOP-style pseudo code. Since the question is tagged homework - I'm leaving the actual implementation to you.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct data {
  const char *element;
  int  visited;
} Data;

#define Size 3

Data Board[Size][Size] = {
    {{ "XY", 0 }, { "YX", 0 },{ "XX", 0 }},
    {{ "XX", 0 }, { "YY", 0 },{ "XY", 0 }},
    {{ "YX", 0 }, { "XY", 0 },{ "XX", 0 }}
};

#define PathLen (Size*Size)

int Path[PathLen];

Data *pos(int *x, int *y){
    if(*x < 0)     *x += Size;
    if(*x >= Size) *x -= Size;
    if(*y < 0)     *y += Size;
    if(*y >= Size) *y -= Size;
    return &Board[*y][*x];
}

void neighbor(int x, int y, int wx, int wy, int level);

void search_path(int x, int y, int level){
    Path[level] = Size * y + x;
    if(level == PathLen - 1){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<PathLen;++i){
            int x = Path[i] % Size;
            int y = Path[i] / Size;
            if(i == PathLen - 1)
                printf("%s\n", Board[y][x].element);
            else
                printf("%s->", Board[y][x].element);
        }
    } else {
        neighbor(x, y, x - 1, y, level);//origin -> left
        neighbor(x, y, x + 1, y, level);//origin -> right
        neighbor(x, y, x, y - 1, level);//origin -> up
        neighbor(x, y, x, y + 1, level);//origin -> down
    }
}
//subroutine
//origin(x,y) -> neighbor(wx,wy)
void neighbor(int x, int y, int wx, int wy, int level){
    Data *wk;
    wk = pos(&wx,&wy);
    if(wk->visited == 0 &&
       (Board[y][x].element[0] == Board[wy][wx].element[0] ||
        Board[y][x].element[1] == Board[wy][wx].element[1])){
        wk->visited = 1;
        search_path(wx, wy, level + 1);
        wk->visited = 0;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int x = 0, y = 0, level = 0;
    Board[0][0].visited = 1;
    search_path(x, y, level);
    return 0;
}
/*
XY->XX->YX->YY->XY->XX->YX->XX->XY
XY->XX->YX->YY->XY->XX->YX->XX->XY
XY->XX->YX->YY->XY->XX->XY->XX->YX
XY->XX->XY->XX->YX->XX->XY->YY->YX
XY->XX->XY->XX->YX->YY->XY->XX->YX
XY->XX->YX->XX->XY->YY->XY->XX->YX
XY->XX->YX->XX->XY->YY->YX->XX->XY
XY->XX->YX->XX->XY->XX->YX->YY->XY
*/
```

Comment: Oh thanks for uploading code but I have already figured it out :). From your code though, I don't get what the Data *pos(int *x, int *y) thing does. Sorry, I'm kind of a beginner.

Comment: function pos is received order index of Board  then return pointer of Board,  and index fixed.